# JavaScript. Devolver variable con asincronismo

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome, asincronismo

Estoy creando una extension de Chrome.

Tengo la siguiente función que quiero que devuelva True o False en función del mensaje respondido. OK true, en caso contrario false.
La función que tiene que devolver el true/false es sendMsgToBackgroundChangeStatus()

```
function sendMsgToBackgroundChangeStatus(){
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'since':'popup', 'activo': !activo}, function(response){
        //alert("Popup: " + response.status);
        //console.log("Popup: " + response.status);
        return response.status;
    }
);
}
if (SendMsgToBackgroundChangeStatus()){
   //block code
} else {
   //block code
}
```

Existen varios problemas.
El primer problema es por la ejecución del código de manera asincrona.
El segundo que no se como puedo sacar el resultado de una función dentro de otra función.

La idea es que segun la respuesta des endMsgToBackgroundChangeStatus() (True o False) se ejecute el código de bloque del condicional (if (SendMsgToBackgroundChangeStatus()))

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.

Comment: Mira este post. Creo que la última de las opciones es la más sencilla: http://justcode.me/questions/question/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Hola:

Gracias por la respuesta.

Pero no me interesa cambiar el método a sincrono.

Otra duda que tengo es como devolver la respuesta de una función que se encuentra dentro de otra función.

Un saludo y gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Avisa si te ha servido al final.

Comment: Hola. Sigo sin ver claro como puedo sacar la variable para hacer posteriormente un condicional.
Actualizo el código (pregunta) para que quede más claro.

Comment: Creo que puedes hacer                                                                         
    `return chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'since':'popup', 'activo': !activo}, 
         function(response){
            //alert("Popup: " + response.status);
            //console.log("Popup: " + response.status);
            return response.status;
        }
    );` o define una función y en lugar de hacer `console.log(reponse....);` haces `myFunción(response);` por ejemplo `myFuncion(response){if (SendMsgToBackgroundChangeStatus()){
   //block code
} else {
   //block code
}}`

Comment: Ahora sí, me dices si te funciona :-)

Comment: Hola de nuevo Victor.

Vale. Entiendo que esto que me dices es para sacar el valor de la variable para fuera, pero sigo con el problema del sincronismo.

El código es para una extensión de Chrome.
Me interesa comunicarme con un backgroup desde un popup. De ahí la función chrome.runtime.sendMessage.

doc: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage

sendMessage
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(string extensionId, any message, object options, function responseCallback)

La función es la encargada de recibir la respuesta del backgroup.

Continuo en el siguiente msg.

Comment: Necesito una condificón if para comprobar que la respuesta es la esperada.
Pero como intentaba explicar, al ser la función asincrona no obtengo el resultado a tiempo para ser evaluado en el if.

Comment: Efectivamente. Voy a recibir un String, (un ok). Dentro de sendMsgToBackgroundChangeStatus() tengo que hacer la conversión a boolean (return (response.status == "OK")) para devolverlo después. Gracias por todas las respuestas. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema se resuelve con el uso de promesas.

```
function sendMsgToBackgroundChangeStatus() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ 'since': 'popup', 'activo': !activo }, function (response) {
                response.status === 'VALID' ? resolve() : reject();
            });
        });
    }

    SendMsgToBackgroundChangeStatus()
        .then(() => console.log('ok'))
        .catch(() => console.log('fail'));
```

Comment: mmm.. esto va bien.. pero que pasa si en realidad la promesa devuelve siempre un valor que se ejecuto correctamente, pero no necesariamente lo que devolvio es true? Podrias explicar un poco mas tu respuesta?

Comment: La promesa se resuelve o se rechaza según el valor de su respuesta dado por response.status. Lo que comentas no entiendo muy bien que quieres decir pero si lo que dices es que el valor de response.status es siempre el mismo valor (cosa que no tendría sentido)... pues claramente la función sendMessage tiene un fallo :).

Comment: OK, perfecto.. podes aclarar eso en la respuesta?

Answer (score -1):

Puedes checar esta liga:

https://eladnava.com/write-synchronous-node-js-code-with-es6-generators/

O también puedes usar librerías como [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) o [FutureJS](https://github.com/FuturesJS/FuturesJS) para evitarte los callbacks hell.

Y si gustas checate esto:

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/